# Google API throws exception at specified lat & long position?

Tags: c#-4.0, google-maps-api-3, google-api

Below is my sample code

```
public static string GetGeoLoc(string latitude, string longitude,
        out string Address_ShortCountryName,
        out string Address_country,
        out string Address_administrative_area_level_1,
        out string Address_administrative_area_level_1_short_name,
        out string Address_administrative_area_level_2,
        out string Address_administrative_area_level_3,
        out string Address_colloquial_area,
        out string Address_locality,
        out string Address_sublocality,
        out string Address_neighborhood)
    {
        Address_ShortCountryName = "";
        Address_country = "";
        Address_administrative_area_level_1 = "";
        Address_administrative_area_level_1_short_name = "";
        Address_administrative_area_level_2 = "";
        Address_administrative_area_level_3 = "";
        Address_colloquial_area = "";
        Address_locality = "";
        Address_sublocality = "";
        Address_neighborhood = "";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        try
        {
            doc.Load("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&sensor=false");
            XmlNode element = doc.SelectSingleNode("//GeocodeResponse/status");
            if (element.InnerText == "ZERO_RESULTS")
            {
                return ("No data available for the specified location");
            }
            else
            {

                element = doc.SelectSingleNode("//GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address");

                string longname = "";
                string shortname = "";
                string typename = "";


                XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("//GeocodeResponse/result/address_component");
                foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        longname = xn["long_name"].InnerText;
                        shortname = xn["short_name"].InnerText;
                        typename = xn["type"].InnerText;

                        switch (typename)
                        {
                            case "country":
                                {
                                    Address_country = longname;
                                    Address_ShortCountryName = shortname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "locality":
                                {
                                    Address_locality = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "sublocality":
                                {
                                    Address_sublocality = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "neighborhood":
                                {
                                    Address_neighborhood = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "colloquial_area":
                                {
                                    Address_colloquial_area = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "administrative_area_level_1":
                                {
                                    Address_administrative_area_level_1 = longname;
                                    Address_administrative_area_level_1_short_name = shortname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "administrative_area_level_2":
                                {
                                    Address_administrative_area_level_2 = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "administrative_area_level_3":
                                {
                                    Address_administrative_area_level_3 = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        clsExHandler.Instance.Write(e);
                    }
                }
                return (element.InnerText);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ("(Address lookup failed: ) " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

try passing latitude as 33.4965 & longitude as -112.205

i'm getting an exception object reference to invalid object in the line

```
**typename = xn["type"].InnerText;**
```

when i debug step by step there is no such attribute like ["type"]

Also there are some other lingual character why?

How could i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with c# and Im not sure if your code is correct at all(e.g. types is not an attribute, it's an elementNode).

Assuming that your code is correct and you can select nodes by using `node['nameOfChildNode']` , when you inspect the XML-File: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=33.4965,-112.205&sensor=false you will see  that there are address_components with 2 `<type>`'s and also address_components without any `<type>` .

I guess your code breaks not at the missing `<type>`, it breaks when you try to access a property(InnerText) of the missing `<type>`.

What you can do: use `selectSingleNode`  to select the `<type>` and when it returns `null` implement a fallback or leave the further processing.

Comment: yes i do accept that type is an element Node and also i'm using `SelectSingleNode` only read my sample code above.

Comment: But `xn["type"]` , that's what we are talking about, you don't use `SelectSingleNode` there. However, when this notation is a valid shorthand for `SelectSingleNode` in C#, that's not the issue here. Visit http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=33.4965,-112.205&sensor=false and you'll see that there is 1 result where the address_component doesn't have a child `<type>` (Scroll down a little bit, there is a result with...I guess japanese characters `USA, Arizona, フェニックス＝メサ＝スコッツデール` , and the 1st `<address_component/>` of this result doesn't have a type, that's the issue)

Answer (score 0):

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=33.4965%20,%20-112.205&sensor=false`

returns

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Therefore

```
XmlNode element = doc.SelectSingleNode("//GeocodeResponse/status");
            if (element.InnerText == "ZERO_RESULTS")
            {
                return ("No data available for the specified location");
            }
```

is not catching `ZERO_RESULTS`.

I am not familiar with C# so I cannot help further.

Comment: The requested URL is http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=33.4965,-112.205&sensor=false